# Sending large byte[] to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

This question has asked sevaral times on SO. But I cannot understand the solutions.
I have WCF service which is implemented to save file sent from client. It is working well with 10kb
This is not suffitiant for me. How to enhance this to work with 100MB.

```
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUpload" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferPoolSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="64000000" maxArrayLength="64000000" maxBytesPerRead="64000000" maxNameTableCharCount="64000000" />
  </binding>
```

I got this exception when sending big file

> *The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.*

**EDITED**

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/Upload/Upload.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUpload"
    contract="DatabaseService.IUpload" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUpload" />
```

Comment: Did you change the size in both the client and server configuration? Is 64000000 enough? It is not the same as 100MB

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd- Yes I increased the size in both sides. What would be the array size for 100MB

Comment: if you are trying to send 100MB you will need to set your data lengths to a value over 104857600(100MB) on both client and server, int.MaxValue(2147483647) should be fine unless your expecting DDOS attacks :)

Comment: @sa_ddam213- I change to that. But still giving same exception

Comment: Could you show us the contract? you might be sending a lot more than you think.

Comment: Can you try to loop from 1MB to 100MB to pin the size where it fail? The size might give some clue to which configuration need to be changed

Comment: @Martheen- it is failing even in 423 KB

Comment: Could you show us how you are using the binding? (Are you using the binding?)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd- i have updated my question. Not sure is that for u are asking. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your web.config to accept large request:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime 
    executionTimeout="90" 
    maxRequestLength="110000" 
  />
 ...
```

maxRequestLength is default 4096 (4mb), change it to 110000 to accept just over 100mb. And make sure your executionTimeout is large enough (in seconds).